# Styling tabBar-indicator with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, themes, actionbarsherlock

I am currently not able to customize the tab-indicator in my app when using Actionbarsherlock. I am trying to change the default color (blue) to white of the indicator. All other customization works as intended. I am not even able to remove the tab-indicator. Have I missed something in my XML-code or what might be the problem? Also note, my min-SDK is set to 14 in the manifest -file. ALL help is needed so I can manage to find the source of the problem :/ Regards

**Tabs.java**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_host);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.LabelTitleAbout);


            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().
                setTabListener(new TabListener<LandingSearch>(this, getString(R.string.LabelSearchTabTitle), LandingSearch.class, null)));

the code continues with the constructor etc...
```

**tab_host.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_navigation_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**values/themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.ML" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
     <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.ML.Tabs" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item> 
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>

</style>
...
```

**drawable/tab_bar_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_blank_off"/>
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected"/>
  <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/>
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

**tab_bar_background_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: May I know why you are using ABS when your minSdkVersion is set to 14? Something wrong with stock `ActionBar`? And I think you should have the following combination in your selector: `<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bar_background_selected"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can fully customized  action bar style using action bar style generator here a link for action bar style generator: 
[Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator)

also you can do from this Example:- [Customize Action bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Vikram said you already using `API 14+` why to use `ActionBarSherlock` over  default action bar,

One can customise ActionBar with different variation using [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).

*Why ABS Tab indicator not changing?*

As you said your action bar tab indicator color is not get changed, here is why
one need to styling attributes where it should belongs to.

```
<style name="Theme.ML.Tabs" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

is not right place to style your `Action Bar Tabs`.

*Solution:-*

```
<style name="Theme.ML" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Theme.ML.Tabs</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.ML.Tabs" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```